# What does "China’s richer tech valuations may have been a draw" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean China's bigger tech companies may have broken even?

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/draw_2

"Still, China’s richer tech valuations may have been a draw, said Sun Mengqi, an analyst at BOCOM International Holdings Co. “There could be a substantial valuation gap between the U.S. and China.”"

Source: http://fortune.com/2018/02/28/zhou-hongyi-net-worth-360-security-technology/

Answer (score 3):

I took that quote to mean that China's richer tech valuations was also a factor that attracted the company to China.  Earlier, the article talked about the main reason why the company moved to China: it wanted to align itself with China's national interest.  But since relocating there, the company stock soared 500%.

So the analyst said: "Still, China's richer tech valuations may have been a draw."  Aligning the company with China's national interest was a draw, but the high tech valuations was also a draw.

A draw can mean a force that attracts or compels you to do something:

The family moved to the suburbs from the city. Cheaper housing may have been a draw.

Comment: That's right. To be a draw means to attract.

Comment: The "valuations" refers to "financial valuations" typical of listed stocks, like  price/earnings, EV/Ebitda, Book Value etc. Rich valuations are a negative because it means that stocks are expensive and likely to be sold (Shanghai index is  lower) and the "valuation gap" refers to cheaper (lower valuations) US tech stocks.